# Dummy Variable by date.

Tags: r

Noob question here. I am trying to create a new column with a dummy variable that explains if a restaurant closed during the recent recession. This data will be merged on to a different dataframe. Thanks in advance.

The max date, combined with another dummy variable, closed, states if a restaurant closed. The dates for the recession are 12/2007 - 06/2009. If a restaurants last reviews was in this range then 1. Not sure if I should use a logical, thanks in advance.

My current code:

```
reviews3 <- ddply(reviews, "business_id", summarise, (max(date)))

newdata <- merge(expandedDataFrame2, reviews3, by="business_id")
```

Structure of the data Frame:

```
str(reviews) data.frame':   229907 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date       : Date, format: "2011-01-26" "2011-07-27" "2012-06-14" "2010-05-27" ...
 $ business_id: chr  "9yKzy9PApeiPPOUJEtnvkg" "ZRJwVLyzEJq1VAihDhYiow" "6oRAC4uyJCsJl1X0WZpVSA" "_1QQZuf4zZOyFCvXc0o6Vg" ...
```

Sample:

```
row.names   date    business_id 
1   X1  2011-01-26  9yKzy9PApeiPPOUJEtnvkg
2   X2  2011-07-27  ZRJwVLyzEJq1VAihDhYiow
3   X3  2012-06-14  6oRAC4uyJCsJl1X0WZpVSA
4   X4  2010-05-27  _1QQZuf4zZOyFCvXc0o6Vg
5   X5  2012-01-05  6ozycU1RpktNG2-1BroVtw
6   X6  2007-12-13  -yxfBYGB6SEqszmxJxd97A
7   X7  2010-02-12  zp713qNhx8d9KCJJnrw1xA
8   X8  2012-07-12  hW0Ne_HTHEAgGF1rAdmR-g
9   X9  2012-08-17  wNUea3IXZWD63bbOQaOH-g
10  X10 2010-08-11  nMHhuYan8e3cONo3PornJA
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dat$dummy <- ifelse(dat$date > as.Date("12/01/2007", format = "%M/%d/%Y") &
                    dat$date < as.Date("06/01/2009", format = "%M/%d/%Y"), 0, 1)

> dat
   row.names       date            business_id dummy
1         X1 2011-01-26 9yKzy9PApeiPPOUJEtnvkg     1
2         X2 2011-07-27 ZRJwVLyzEJq1VAihDhYiow     1
3         X3 2012-06-14 6oRAC4uyJCsJl1X0WZpVSA     1
4         X4 2010-05-27 _1QQZuf4zZOyFCvXc0o6Vg     1
5         X5 2012-01-05 6ozycU1RpktNG2-1BroVtw     1
6         X6 2007-12-13 -yxfBYGB6SEqszmxJxd97A     0
7         X7 2010-02-12 zp713qNhx8d9KCJJnrw1xA     1
8         X8 2012-07-12 hW0Ne_HTHEAgGF1rAdmR-g     1
9         X9 2012-08-17 wNUea3IXZWD63bbOQaOH-g     1
10       X10 2010-08-11 nMHhuYan8e3cONo3PornJA     1
```

Comment: Awesome! I always have such trouble with dates. Thanks for this.

Comment: Actually, I am now getting this error. Not sure what to make of it.


    Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "dummy", value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 11537