# How to change from event data to time-series cross-sectional data with event dummies?

Tags: r, datetime, transformation, dummy-variable

I have been given a dataset that lists dates for specific events by country in the manner below.

```
country date1 date2   
1    03/01/2012    05/01/2012
2    05/04/2012    12/10/2012
3    07/12/2012    20/03/2012
4    04/02/2012    24/12/2012
```

What I need to do with this data is create panel data for country/year/month/day levels. I would want to create a dummy variable for each event.

```
country year month   day
1  2012    01    01
1  2012    01    02
1  2012    01    03
1  2012    01    04
1  2012    01    05
1  2012    01    06
```

The end result of this would look like this with each country panel having either a 0 or a 1 for every year/month/day in each separate event variable.

```
country year month day event1 event2 
1  2012    01    01    0    0 
1  2012    01    02    0    0
1  2012    01    03    1    0
1  2012    01    04    1    0
1  2012    01    05    1    1
1  2012    01    06    1    1
```

The question is how to most efficiently get from the data that I do have to the data structure that I need. I found a previous question that had a similar question ([Dummy Variable by date.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163529/dummy-variable-by-date?rq=1)), but this question did not deal with panel data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution. The idea is to use `tidyr::complete` to generate the full set of date-country combinations that you want. Then it's easy to use `tidyr::spread` to split the values of `has_event` into separate columns for each event and create the right column names with the `sep` argument. The rest is just cleaning up - converting the date into separate `year`, `month`, `day` columns, removing extraneous columns, and replacing the `NA` with `0` in the event columns. This should be robust to more countries, more events per country, or large date ranges.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
tbl <- read_table2(
  "country date1 date2
  1    03/01/2012    05/01/2012
  2    05/04/2012    12/10/2012
  3    07/12/2012    20/03/2012
  4    04/02/2012    24/12/2012"
)
#> Warning in rbind(names(probs), probs_f): number of columns of result is not
#> a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
#> Warning: 1 parsing failure.
#> row # A tibble: 1 x 5 col     row col   expected actual        file         expected   <int> <chr> <chr>    <chr>         <chr>        actual 1     4 date2 ""       embedded null literal data file # A tibble: 1 x 5

tbl %>%
  gather(event, date, date1:date2) %>%
  mutate(date = dmy(date)) %>%
  complete(country, date = seq.Date(min(date), max(date), 1)) %>%
  mutate(
    event = str_remove_all(event, "date"),
    has_event = ifelse(is.na(event), 0, 1)
    ) %>%
  spread(event, has_event, sep = "") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(event1:event2), replace_na, 0) %>%
  mutate(
    year = year(date),
    month = month(date),
    day = day(date)
  ) %>%
  select(country, year:day, event1:event2)
#> # A tibble: 1,428 x 6
#>    country  year month   day event1 event2
#>      <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1       1 2012.    1.     3     1.     0.
#>  2       1 2012.    1.     4     0.     0.
#>  3       1 2012.    1.     5     0.     1.
#>  4       1 2012.    1.     6     0.     0.
#>  5       1 2012.    1.     7     0.     0.
#>  6       1 2012.    1.     8     0.     0.
#>  7       1 2012.    1.     9     0.     0.
#>  8       1 2012.    1.    10     0.     0.
#>  9       1 2012.    1.    11     0.     0.
#> 10       1 2012.    1.    12     0.     0.
#> # ... with 1,418 more rows
```

Created on 2018-03-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).